# Change one IP without disrupting connections to second?

Tags: networking, centos6, ip-address

I have a CentOS 6 box that has two IP Addresses on one physical interface - One the IP assigned to the interface via the netconfig scripts, and the second a "virtual" IP assigned  to the same interface via a pacemaker service. I would like to change the "physical" IP address, but I don't want to disrupt any connections to the virtual IP address. Is this possible, and if so, how?

Always before when I wanted to change an IP, I would simply modify the netconfig script and then run `service network restart`, but I would think that would terminate any connections to the virtual IP.

Answer (score 3):

Generally I do like your current approach as that will ensure that you end up with a tested & valid configuration and no nasty surprises upon next reboot. But the [`ip`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ip) command should meet your needs:

```
ip address add NEWIFADDR dev STRING
ip addr del OLDIFADDR dev STRING
```

Comment: While that worked to change the IP without restarting the interface, as soon as I deleted the old IP address I lost the virtual IP as well. `pcs status` showed the service as stopped, and I couldn't figure out any way to get it to start again, short of deleting and recreating the virtual IP service. So, unfortunately, while it looked promising that approach didn't work.